# Is it possible to use reflection to turn a string into a function in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

```
public delegate void SimpleDelegate();

public void mycode()
{
string str = "myfunction"; 

/*somehow use reflection to turn str into myfunction so this will compile*/
SimpleDelegate simpleDelegate = new SimpleDelegate(str);

}

public void myfunction() { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the method info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx

Convert it to a delegate

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53cz7sc6.aspx

Edit - Here is a small Linqpad snippet where I've setup an extension method off String to create delegates. There is no error checking!

```
void Main()
{
    var simpleDelegate = "test".CreateDelegate<Func<string>>(new Test());
    simpleDelegate().Dump();
}

class Test
{
    public string test() { return "hi"; }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T CreateDelegate<T>(this string methodName,object instance) where T : class
    {
        return Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), instance, methodName) as T;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection to get a method:

```
GetType().GetMethod(str).Invoke(this, new object[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

This walks you through exactly how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Reflection_Tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Reflection.Emit` to create code but this would not take a string. Another alternative is [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) which can take string.

## Soultion

You can use Compiler to build an assembly and load. Look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655).